# how to fill with spaces an inserted expression to a given length during substitution in vim regex

Tags: regex, vim

I want to implement behavior similar to `setw()` and `setfill()` in c ++. For example i want to replace expression:

```
15.8
```

with:

```
_______15,8
```

in text and:

```
10000
```

with:

```
_10000
```

Comment: Do you really want to replace point with comma?

Comment: Yes. Actually it is need because our version of excell read fractional numbers with comma and can't read with point. This is due to localization. I want to know fast way to edit texts for this situations. Really no matter there is dot or comma. The main trouble is size of field and alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement such behavior, the ability to [evaluate the substitute string as an expression](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression) is helpful.
If e. g. we put

```
let s:fill = "_"
func! Setfill(fill)
    let s:fill = a:fill
endfunc

let s:width = 8
func! Setw(width)
    let s:width = a:width
endfunc

func! Fild()
    let m = submatch(0)
    return repeat(s:fill, s:width-len(m)) . m
endfunc
```

in a vimrc file, we can use

```
:call Setw(6)
:%s/10000/\=Fild()/
```

Comment: Instead of `len()`, it' would be better to use [`strcharlen()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#strcharlen()) in case of multi-bytes characters.